# adding property to pybind11 class instance

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am starting from https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example to which I added a simple struct `Value` in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
struct Value {
    int a, b;
};
```

exposed in python with:

```cpp
py::class_<Value> cl(m, "Value");
  cl.def(pybind11::init<>());
  cl.def_readwrite("a", &Value::a);
  cl.def_readwrite("b", &Value::b);
```

My problem is that any instance of Value is not extensible, and I wish to complete this struct in python, by information available only at runtime:

```py
>>> import cmake_example
>>> val = cmake_example.Value()
>>> val.a = 5
>>> val.b
0
>>> val.c = 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'cmake_example.Value' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `py::dynamic_attr()` when binding the class:

```cpp
py::class_<Value> cl(m, "Value", py::dynamic_attr());
//                               ^-- here
  cl.def(pybind11::init<>());
  cl.def_readwrite("a", &Value::a);
  cl.def_readwrite("b", &Value::b);
```

See [pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#dynamic-attributes).

Comment: thanks a lot. I managed to miss this in the doc....